# how to Change the asp response Content-Type at run time

Tags: asp-classic, mime-types

i have java web service, returns an Object contains couple of variables data, this web service being called in ASP code, but asp code always getting the Mime Type is "text/plain". even though I did setup the below
Response.ContentType = "application/xml"
and not parsing the web service results and error out type mismatch at loadXML.
Can some one suggest how to change the mime type in ASP code at runtime? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your Java web service returns text/plain as Content Type.

Changing the ASP content type doesn't have any bearing on that, as that's to do with what Content Type your ASP page displays.